# mvnw install dockerfile:build failed Could not find goal 'build' in plugin

Tags: maven, docker

I'm trying to build my first docker image using the command `mvnw install dockerfile:build`, but I have the following error:

```
Could not find goal 'build' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2 
among available ....
```

and there's a list of available "goals". Build is not there, but there's build-classpath, so I've tried using that and then this is the error:

```
Could not find goal 'build-classpath' in plugin com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.9 among available goals build, help, push, tag
```

So both commands do not work. I'm using Windows and this is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
            <goal>push</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Where there's the "build" goal I'm using. What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You're configuring `goals` `build` and `push` which belong to the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` on the `maven-dependency-plugin` where they are actually unknown. Pull those goals down to the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` and try again please.

If not already happened, you can also follow this [quite basic example](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven#example).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've don what you said but now the errors is " Could not find goal 'unpack' in plugin com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.9 among available goals build, help, push, tag"

Comment: Unpack? No, I just spoke of moving the `build` and `push` goals and not the `unpack` goal. The latter one belongs to the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html).

Comment: Yes, is what I did... I didn't move unpack goal, but the error is the same

Comment: Strange. Then let's elaborate further about your Maven call `mvnw install dockerfile:build`. IMHO it should read `mvnw install dockerfile-maven-plugin:build` to refer to the correct plugin. Could you please verify?